# Change dimension values based on date selected on filter

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular

I am unable to achieve the next DAX. I have 2 tables: **Revenue** and **Type**.

I want to display: "latest type", at the selected FY in a filter. (That is, if FY 20 is selected, the type shall be the one valid **on 31-May-2020**).

Revenue table:

[image]

Type table:

[image]

(Date is dd-mm-year)

When the user selects FY20, I would like to display all Revenue data like:

[image]

That is, on 31-May-2020, the valid Type was 3 for customer 15; and Type 2 for customer 492.

(When the user selects FY21, the same shall be displayed since on 31-May-2021, for customer 15 the valid Type was 3 and Type 2 for customer 492. )

When the user selects FY22, I want to display:

[image]

(on 31-May-2022, the valid Type was 6 for customer 15)
(on 31-May-2022, the valid Type was 2 for customer 492)

and so on...

Is this possible? (I am also concerned performance-wise)
(If this cannot be done in DAX, I can do it with a very large table in sql...)

Comment: Can you explain this part "That is, if FY 20 is selected, the type shall be the one valid on 31-May-2020" how do you estimate this date for FY20 ?

Comment: (For this case FY ends 31-may and starts 1-june) So, I have a visible filter on Fiscal Year, so the user can select either 2022, 2021 or 2020. Whatever FY they choose, I pick the last day of the said FY and I would have to fetch the valid Type on that day.